# Wiring up a switch with only one wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

So I only have one wire in my switch box and it’s going up to the light. I can only grab my power from the ceiling but I don’t want to fight inside of a plaster wall to get a wire back down. Is there anyway possible just using that one wire that I could make this work.

Comment: Do you mean one wire, or one cable containing black, white, and green or bare wires? If it's the latter, this could be a switch loop; see many past answers about that. If it's the former, you can't do _anything_; with it.

Comment: You have a switch...Is it working now?   It's not clear what your situation is but you may find this useful:  https://www.thisoldhouse.com/electrical/21016047/how-to-install-a-wireless-light-switch

Comment: Photo of the switch and box, as they are wired now., would be helpful. Photo of how the light fixture is wired up would also help; that would help us confirm whether this really is a switch loop.

Comment: Have we established a canonical Answer for "what is a switch loop, how is it wired, what colors slight I expect to see (remembering that colors differ by country and by electrician's competence), how do I figure it out and put it back together if I've already fully disassembled it?" to use as a master Duplicate Of?